# Scala Package for "FileInputStream / FileOutputStream & Property

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there any package available in Scala corresponding to below packages available in Java ?

```
import java.io._
val input = new FileInputStream(propertyfilePath)

import java.util.Properties
val prop = new Properties()
```

Comment: Are you facing any issues? These classes are compatible with Scala too.

Comment: thanks for the response..
i'm not facing any issue with this code but wanted to check whether any Scala package is available to achieve the same or not ?